# Increase max row size in HIVE

Tags: pyspark, hive, hive-configuration

I have a pyspark job with these configs:

```
self.spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example") \
.config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true") \
.config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict") \
.config("hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions", "5000000") \
.config("hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode", "1000000") \
.enableHiveSupport() \
.getOrCreate()
```

I can not find anywhere how to set a configuration to increase the `max row size` to `150mb`. I found the command only in impala.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such configuration in `Hive` because Hive is not all-in-memory and can process rows of virtually unlimited size. Single string can be up to `2Gb` in size, and [the number of columns can be many tens of thousands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46339359/2700344), though you may need (most probably) many thousands rows to fit in single container memory, but usually mapper or reducer size is more than 1G and can be increased.